# How to preserve the font formatting while replacing the data label on point using python pptx

Tags: python, python-pptx

I am replacing the existing labels on series in stacked bar chart using python pptx package. The labels are numbers and need red/green colors. The text is updating fine but it loses the size and doesn't seem to apply color correctly.

This is the function I am using.

```
def add_data_labels(chart, series_name, data_labels):
    for idx, series in enumerate(chart.plots[0].series):
        if series.name == series_name:
            for idx, point in enumerate(series.points):
                point.data_label.text_frame.text = data_labels[idx]
                color = GREEN if data_labels[idx] > 0 else RED
                point.data_label.font.color.rgb = RGBColor(*color)
     return
```

Answer (score 2):

To preserve existing font properties while updating the text, you need to first capture the existing font properties and reapply them after updating the text. Then for color, make sure your using the `RGBColor` object correctly.

Here's how you can mod your funct to address these issues:

```py
from pptx.util import Pt
from pptx.dml.color import RGBColor

GREEN = (0, 128, 0)  # You can replace this with the actual RGB values
RED = (255, 0, 0)  # You can replace this with the actual RGB values

def add_data_labels(chart, series_name, data_labels):
    for idx, series in enumerate(chart.plots[0].series):
        if series.name == series_name:
            for idx, point in enumerate(series.points):
                # Capture existing font properties
                existing_font_size = point.data_label.text_frame.paragraphs[0].font.size
                existing_font_name = point.data_label.text_frame.paragraphs[0].font.name

                # Update the label text
                point.data_label.text_frame.text = str(data_labels[idx])

                # Reapply the existing font properties
                point.data_label.text_frame.paragraphs[0].font.size = existing_font_size or Pt(12)  # Default to 12pt if not set
                point.data_label.text_frame.paragraphs[0].font.name = existing_font_name or 'Arial'  # Default to Arial if not set

                # Update color
                color = GREEN if data_labels[idx] > 0 else RED
                point.data_label.text_frame.paragraphs[0].font.color.rgb = RGBColor(*color)
                
    return
```